# Making a Prediction Sagemaker Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, amazon-sagemaker

I have trained and deployed a model in Pytorch with Sagemaker. I am able to call the endpoint and get a prediction. I am using the default input_fn() function (i.e. not defined in my serve.py).

```
model = PyTorchModel(model_data=trained_model_location,
                     role=role,
                     framework_version='1.0.0',
                     entry_point='serve.py',
                     source_dir='source')
predictor = model.deploy(initial_instance_count=1, instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge')
```

A prediction can be made as follows:

```
input ="0.12787057,  1.0612601,  -1.1081504"
predictor.predict(np.genfromtxt(StringIO(input), delimiter=",").reshape(1,3) )
```

I want to be able to serve the model with REST API and am HTTP POST using lambda and API gateway. I was able to use invoke_endpoint() for this with an XGBOOST model in Sagemaker this way. I am not sure what to send into the body for Pytorch.

```
client = boto3.client('sagemaker-runtime')
response = client.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=ENDPOINT  ,
ContentType='text/csv',
Body=???)
```

I believe I need to understand how to write the customer input_fn to accept and process the type of data I am able to send through invoke_client. Am I on the right track and if so, how could the input_fn be written to accept a csv from invoke_endpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are on the right track. You can send csv-serialized input to the endpoint without using the `predictor` from the SageMaker SDK, and using other SDKs such as `boto3` which is installed in lambda:

```
import boto3
runtime = boto3.client('sagemaker-runtime')

payload = '0.12787057,  1.0612601,  -1.1081504'

response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(
    EndpointName=ENDPOINT_NAME,
    ContentType='text/csv',
    Body=payload.encode('utf-8'))

result = json.loads(response['Body'].read().decode())
```

This will pass to the endpoint a csv-formatted input, that you may need to reshape back in the `input_fn` to put in the appropriate dimension expected by the model.

for example:

```
def input_fn(request_body, request_content_type):
    if request_content_type == 'text/csv':
        return torch.from_numpy(
            np.genfromtxt(StringIO(request_body), delimiter=',').reshape(1,3))
```

**Note**: I wasn't able to test the specific `input_fn` above with your input content and shape but I used the approach on Sklearn RandomForest couple times, and looking at the [Pytorch SageMaker serving doc](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using_pytorch.html#model-serving) the above rationale should work.

Don't hesitate to use endpoint logs in Cloudwatch to diagnose any inference error (available from the endpoint UI in the console), those logs are usually **much more verbose** that the high-level logs returned by the inference SDKs

Comment: What does payload.encode('utf-8') do? Does it make a byte array which is what invoke_endpoint expects? But if you use predictor.predict it expects a numpy array?

Comment: the predictor from python SDK is high-level, and does the serialization from numpy or other on your behalf! in boto3, you have to decide which serialization to use and do it yourself

Comment: Shall we implement the input_fn function should in the entry point python file? Or where it should be implemented?

Comment: @kelvin.aaa2 yes in the entry_point sent to the PyTorchModel class, or in the PyTorch Estimator if you're deploying directly post-training